# An array to assign even and odd numbers

Tags: c

I was thinking of an array to find how to assign even and odd numbers in two successive arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

    int main()
    {
    int a[100],odd[100],even[100],i,j,n;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
    a[i]=0;
    odd[i]=0;
    even[i]=0;
    }
    printf("Enter the number of elements which you want to check as even or odd");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    if(a[i]%2==0)
    a[i]=even[i];
    else
    a[i]=odd[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("The set of even numbers is %d"),even[i];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("The set of even numbers is %d"),odd[i];
    return 0;
    }
```

The program does not run. I can not spot the mistake right now. Can anyone spot the mistake? The compiler shows out 
**Segmentation fault

...Program finished with exit co

de 139

Press ENTER to exit console.

**

Comment: You mean other than the obvious error of assigning to a instead of odd or even in you loop? What specifically does *does not run* mean? You need to be clear and specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the suggestion.  Should i give screenshots of the compilation?

Comment: You're not initializing variables before using them. For instance, you declare `n`, but don't assign a value to it, but use it in your first `for` loop.

Comment: @KenWhite ok so i have to assign 0 to it?

Comment: No. Read your own code. It says `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)` in three separate places - what do you expect `n` to be to end the loops? You use it as the exit condition with `i<=n`.

Comment: @KenWhite i see ut should be scanned at the top; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am try to point some mistakes of the code by using the comment .

And I think this code also has logical problem is that you want to put a list of numbers to odd-array and even-array,but the initial vaule of the even and odd array is all zero.

When you divide the list of number into tow array,you are not overwrite all of the initial value,that will cause there are some zero value be printed at last but they are not belong to odd neither even.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

        int main()
        {
        int a[100],odd[100],even[100],i,j,n;
    //you should first assign a vaule to n and then use n
    //and be careful for the value of the n,
    //it should not larger than the size of the array,or it will overflow.
        for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
        a[i]=0;
        odd[i]=0;
        even[i]=0;
        }
    //put below two lines to the front of the above for-loop
        printf("Enter the number of elements which you want to check as even or odd");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
        a[i]=even[i];
        else
        a[i]=odd[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    //you type a wrong 'printf' satement,here is the right way
    //printf("The set of even numbers is %d",even[i]);
        printf("The set of even numbers is %d"),even[i];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("The set of even numbers is %d"),odd[i];//you type a wrong 'printf' satement
        return 0;
        }
```